# Is there a way to make a child process output stream flush its data more frequently?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pipe a child process' standard output to the parent's standard output:

```
import {exec} from 'child_process';

console.log(new Date() + " starting")
const child = exec(/* some command */);
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

This works, but the child process generates data quite slowly relative to the size of the pipe's buffer. The data comes in large chunks and not frequently.

For example, if I watch the child output stream like this:

```
child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(new Date(), data.length));
```

The output is

```
2017-11-15T21:53:44.128Z starting
2017-11-15T21:53:58.319Z 8192
2017-11-15T21:54:02.321Z 8192
2017-11-15T21:54:07.384Z 8192
2017-11-15T21:54:11.333Z 8192
2017-11-15T21:54:15.281Z 8192
2017-11-15T21:54:19.008Z 3967
```

Is there a way to have the child output stream use a smaller buffer or flush more frequently?

Comment: The command must flush its buffers. There's usually no way of forcing a flush externally.

Comment: It's the parent that needs to flush, not the child.

Comment: So does it make sense for me to read the stream manually in a loop? Would that make the data accessible to me when I want it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: @Matt the underlying child process prints frequently to its output (just not a lot relative to the size of the node stream buffer, it appears). There's no pipe in the child process command either.

Comment: @Matt but yes the problem I am experiencing is exactly as described in your link (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky have you tried `spawn` over `exec`? e.g. `spawn(/*some command*/, [], { stdio: 'inherit' });`. This will force the child process to use the `stdio` of the parent.

Comment: The same semantics hold, when there isn't a tty or specific flushes by the child process, the output to node will be buffered by the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS and child process are in control of output buffering.

As an example, Python has a `-u` option that causes writes to be flushed (also the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` env var). The following example adapted from the question shows the difference in behaviour of a command that writes an integer to screen every second when using unbuffered and normal output.

```
const {exec} = require('child_process')

function run(cmd){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("%s starting %s", Date.now(), cmd)
    const child = exec(cmd)
    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
    child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
    child.on('exit', exit => {
      console.log('%s exit', Date.now(), exit)
      if ( exit === 0 ) return resolve(exit)
      reject(new Error(exit))
    })
  })
}

async function go(){
  await run('python -uc "import time; [print(i,str(time.sleep(1))) for i in range(10)]"')
  await run('python -c "import time; [print(i,str(time.sleep(1))) for i in range(10)]"')
}

go()
```

If the child process being run doesn't have an equivalent option or config to flush output then [this Unix + Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) includes a number of tricks to disable buffered output by modifying how the child process is run, by either allocating a pseudo terminal or modifying it's buffers directly.

There's also [`node-pty`](https://github.com/Tyriar/node-pty) and [`node-pty2`](https://github.com/edjubuh/node-pty) which will spawn processes with a pseudo terminal which would be similar to what expects [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) command does. I've not used either module before though so can't vouch for them.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for this answer and your comment above. I haven't had time to explore this too much further. I can't rely on `expectes`/`unbuffer`, but will check out the npm packages.